# boost::spiritのセマンティックアクションで関数を使いたい

Tags: c++, boost

現在 boost::spirit を使って関数電卓を作っています。

四則演算は次のような感じで実装できますが、

`(double_>>'+'>>double_)[_val=_1+_2]`

関数の場合、例えば二つの数の平均を計算する関数などを考えたとき、

`(double_>>','>>double_)[_val=Average(_1,_2)]`

という感じにすることはできますか？

Comment: 質問内容を含むようにタイトルを変更させていただきましたが、もし間違っていれば編集をお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

セマンティックアクション`[]`の中に、Boost.LambdaやC++ラムダ式を書く方法はどうでしょうか。

まずはBoost.Lambdaを使う例です。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/at_c.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_parse.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_real.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_action.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char_.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_sequence.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

namespace bll = boost::lambda;

double Average(const boost::fusion::vector<double, double>& x)
{
    return (boost::fusion::at_c<0>(x) + boost::fusion::at_c<1>(x)) * 0.5;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "1,2";
    auto first = s.begin();
    double val;
    bool success = parse(
        first,
        s.end(),
        (double_ >> ',' >> double_)[bll::var(val) = bll::bind(Average, bll::_1)]
    );
    if (success)
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

こっちはラムダ式を使う例です。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/at_c.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_parse.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_real.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_action.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char_.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_sequence.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

namespace bll = boost::lambda;

double Average(const boost::fusion::vector<double, double>& x)
{
    return (boost::fusion::at_c<0>(x) + boost::fusion::at_c<1>(x)) * 0.5;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "1,2";
    auto first = s.begin();
    double val;
    bool success = parse(
        first,
        s.end(),
        (double_ >> ',' >> double_)[([&](const auto& x) {val = Average(x);})]
    );
    if (success)
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html#phoenix.modules.function.adapting_functions.boost_phoenix_adapt_function)を使えば、通常の関数をセマンティックアクション内で使える形に変換してくれるようです。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
using namespace boost::phoenix;

double Average_(double d1, double d2)
{
    return (d1 + d2) * 0.5;
}

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Average, Average_, 2)

int main()
{
    std::string s = "1,2";
    auto first = s.begin();
    double val;
    bool success = parse(
        first,
        s.end(),
        (double_ >> ',' >> double_)[ref(val) = Average(_1, _2)]
    );
    if (success)
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

通常の関数を変換せずにそのまま使いたい場合は、[bind](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/bind/binding_functions.html)を使えばよさそうです。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
using namespace boost::phoenix;

double Average(double d1, double d2)
{
    return (d1 + d2) * 0.5;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "1,2";
    auto first = s.begin();
    double val;
    bool success = parse(
        first,
        s.end(),
        (double_ >> ',' >> double_)[ref(val) = bind(Average, _1, _2)]
    );
    if (success)
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```